# How can I make iptables service start automatically after reboot on CenOS/RHEL7?

Tags: centos, rhel, iptables, firewall

I am having a few issues with a newly installed home server I am preparing. I have installed CentOS7 on it and I found that port 80 and 443 are off by default. I therefore added them to the iptables with the following commands:

```
iptables -I INPUT 5 -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT 5 -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
service iptables save
```

I also installed the iptable service which was not present. The problem is that every time I reboot the machine the new configurations are wiped.

I tried to add the the iptable service to chkconfig but I get the following error:

```
[root@CentOS-7]# chkconfig --add iptables
error reading information on service iptables: No such file or directory
```

I presume that the reason I get this error is because there is no iptable script in /etc/init.d/ however has anyone any ideas if I am actually doing the right thing and/or if there is an easier more solid way to do this? If not how can I solve this problem? In the end I just need to use my home server as a web/mail server...

I have also tried to use the 'systemctl enable iptables' command as flemingovirus kindly suggested but with no success. After I entered the command I got the following output:

```
ln -s '/usr/lib/systemd/system/iptables.service' '/etc/systemd/system/basic.target.wants`/iptables.service'`
```

UPDATE: I have looked at the iptables and the command "service iptables save" has worked properly. The problem seem to be due to the service not starting at reboot. I have managed to get the service running at reboot after adding the following line to /etc/rc.local

```
systemctl start  iptables.service
```

however I wonder why the 'systemctl enable iptables' command is not working in this case. Am I missing something? Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Although this question is old, I came across the same issue and discovered the solution [here](http://www.certdepot.net/rhel7-disable-firewalld-use-iptables/).

```
systemctl mask firewalld
systemctl stop firewalld
```

Basically firewalld conflicts iptables and so will prevent iptables from loading:

```
# cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service 
[Unit]
Description=firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon
Before=network.target
Before=libvirtd.service
Before=NetworkManager.service
Conflicts=iptables.service ip6tables.service ebtables.service

...
```

I was able to solve this by masking firewalld to ensure it does not start automatically and will never be started thereafter. Of course you will need to ensure iptables is enabled:

```
systemctl enable iptables
```

Comment: The document you reference does not say that firewalld prevents iptables from loading, where did you get that idea?

Answer (score 4):

init scripts are gone. Now its `systemctl`. Its out there in all CentOS7 docs. To chkconfig ipatables or to start iptables service at startup you need to use this:-

systemctl enable iptables

You should checkout simple things to be known about systemctl at the Cyberciti docs on [iptables](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rhel-centos-linux-7-restart-networking-command-line/).

Comment: Hi flemingovirus, I did trying what you have suggested and also looked at the link but it is still not working. Any ideas? thanks

Comment: @Dave did you check where the iptables is? Is it /sbin/iptables itself? Check it out with `dpkg -L iptables`

Comment: [root@CentOS-7}# rpm -ql iptables-services.x86_64
/etc/sysconfig/ip6tables
/etc/sysconfig/iptables
/usr/lib/systemd/system/ip6tables.service
/usr/lib/systemd/system/iptables.service
/usr/libexec/initscripts/legacy-actions/ip6tables
/usr/libexec/initscripts/legacy-actions/ip6tables/panic
/usr/libexec/initscripts/legacy-actions/ip6tables/save
/usr/libexec/initscripts/legacy-actions/iptables
/usr/libexec/initscripts/legacy-actions/iptables/panic
/usr/libexec/initscripts/legacy-actions/iptables/save
/usr/libexec/iptables
/usr/libexec/iptables/ip6tables.init
/usr/libexec/iptables/iptables.init

Comment: there is no dpkg so I used rpm instead. is this output sensible? thanks

Comment: also with regards to where iptables is yes, its under /sbin/iptables

Comment: Oh I am so sorry, my mind got mixed up with another question. ok forget about the location of iptables. So what do you get when you use `systemctl`? Post the output on your question.

Comment: @Dave the output of systemctl says it has been put for startup. Check with a reboot.

Comment: Hi yes I did several times but no luck unfortunately

Comment: I cannot understand why these rules are forgotten after reboot

Comment: Could be interaction with `firewald`? (See @zanegray's answer.)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should try `#chkconfig --add /sbin/iptables` this will recognize the "iptables". then you should create a script for your iptables configuration and then make that scrip to start on boot.
create a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
iptables -I INPUT 5 -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT 5 -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
/sbin/service iptables save
```

and name  it for example `myfirewall`. make it executable with `chmod +x myfirewall` and write this `./myfirewall` in `/etc/rc.local` to start the script on boot.

Comment: thanks but I get the following error: "error reading information on service iptables: No such file or directory" Also, to me it looks like a really complicated way to do this. Is there no other way to implement this in CentOS. In the end I am only trying to use it as a standard web/mail server. How can one use a web server if port 80 and 443 are not opened by default. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: iptables is builtin in Centos. i think you had a problem in installation. please try `$sudo service iptables status` and write output in comment.